# Does the verse in Tehillim 147:4 imply that one cannot name a star after a person?

Tags: halacha, names, tehilim-psalms, astronomy

Usually, around Mother's Day and Valentines Day, I hear a radio commercial suggesting that, as a gift to your loved one, you can name a star after him / her. (Amazing gimmick - no inventory!!)

In reading *Torah Temimah's* explanation on this verse "G-d counts the number of the stars and calls each by name",

שהקב"ה קורא לכולם בדבור אחד ולכל אחד 
ואחד בשמו המיוחד לו, וכל השמות כוללם
בדבור אחד, וכל כוכב וכוכב שומע שמו כשקורא
אותם הקב"ה

(Loose translation) - "G-d calls out to all of them in one calling and to each one in its specified name..."

it seems to imply that God has already assigned a name to each star. The ad implies that the star has never been named, previously. So, if I have my name registered with the notion that the star has never been previously named, am I not denyong what God has already done?

Comment: God calls it a סוס but I call it a horse. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you know all of God's names for the stars? Maybe the name you give it happens to be the name God calls it. ; Why don't you consider your name to be a nickname? ; God created light. Does that mean that everytime I turn on my lamp I am somehow impinging on God? ; Finally, the Gemara clearly refers to stars by their Greek names. if they can do it, so can you.

Comment: @Shmu'el - place an answer, please. Your reasoning sounds credible. Please include location of the Gemarrah ref.

Comment: Berachot 58b, Pesachim 94, Shabbat 156a, ERUVIN 56.  [This article](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/2052-astronomy) lists more places, but those are the one's I've checked and confirmed.

Comment: See also Job 38:31-32

Comment: RE somehow denying God - http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0009_0_09507.html

Comment: See also Job 38.

Answer (score 1):

I may expand on this answer later, but the short version is: **No,** the verse does not imply that, and no, you are not denying anything God has done.

- We don't learn halacha from poetry in Tehillim.
- That verse isn't implying anything about the stars or their names, other than God is so great that He can name all the stars.
- Names are subjective, not objective.
- Just because God does something doesn't mean you can't do it also.
- A person's actions cannot impinge on God's glory or ability.

*citation needed*

Comment: And, from a *hashkafic* perspective, maybe we should stop looking in Torah for things we *can't* do and start looking for positive things that we *can* do.

Comment: The first point isn't completely true. The Gemara often leans halachos from random pesukim in Nach.